# Are phrasing requests on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm bewildered, as [the question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1853/2423) was upvoted 10 times, but [this answer disagreeing](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2233/2423) was upvoted 9 times. So which prevails?

Answer (score 3):

## The Help Center prevails.

It's clearly stated in the [Help Center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that questions that ask us to rewrite text or otherwise tell you what to say are off topic.

Comment: I fail to see how your answer even addresses the question. As far as I am aware the help-center is merely a collection of this communities current rules, which can be changed via meta discussion & votes. As such I would deem it important for OP to understand how to interpret the votes ...

Answer (score -1):

I understand your confusion!

As per [this meta:](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/voting-on-meta-questions)

- If a question is a good/important question, (weather you disagree with it or not) up vote the question. This makes this question more likely to get broad attention and user-participation to get a strong mandate
- Then post or up vote an answer stating reflecting your view. The highest-voted answer reflects the current majority will of the community.
- **With one exception:** there are some questions tagged as *feature-request*.
  For those, you upvote the question if you want to see that feature implemented, and you downvote it if you think the feature is a bad idea.

So in your example the community voted that:

1. Its an important question (+15/-5 as of this writing)
2. Phrasing question should be on topic (+12/-2)

Now in theory the community makes the rules. So if this discussion is considered mature enough, the help-center should be changed to reflect that. As per @Catija s comment there is further discussion <sub>(could´t find it, will update if link is provided)</sub> to be found about this topic, so there may be more arguments to consider.

TLDR;

**The answer with the highest up votes prevails.** But resulting policy may be affected by further discussions.

Comment: who ever downvoted this care to explain where this is wrong?

Comment: If you feel that the text in the help center should be changed. Make a separate meta post about that.

Comment: @sphennings: I don´t feel anything, just tired to explain OP how meta is supposed to work, as per my understanding / as it was explained to me. (also I´m personally against allowing phrasing questions)

Comment: Then why propose it?

Comment: Where did I propose anything? If I´d want to propose anything of that sort I´d make a new meta with topic "Lets update the help-center to adhere to recent meta decisions" or something like this ...

Comment: There are at least two other answers elsewhere on the site with huge support for banning this and the answer on that question is pretty much inscrutable as far as it goes to set any sort of policy.

Comment: @Catija: I am not sympathetic to the cause of that question, just wanted to stay in OP´s example to explain how voting works. If you have a reference for me for the pro-banning-treads I will gladly incorporate that in my answer. (will try to find them myself, now)